# Error while i'm uploading an iphone app using application loader

Tags: ios, iphone

this is my first question here :) so i hope that i can find a useful answers for my problem,
i have made an iphone application by Mobione , and i already have the ipa file for my application , and i'm trying to upload it on itunes using the application loader but i'm facing this errors on the picture

http://oi62.tinypic.com/4id5k.jpg

so could any one tell me how to avoid this messages and upload my application on Apple Store?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have selected the correct provisioning profile to build the IPA, since you are uploading on Apple App store, so DEVELOPER or ADHOC/DISTRIBUTION provisions should NOT be selected.